# Getting the scale right for a line chart for a simple CSV in D3 v4

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have the following [CSV file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Ciwan1859/3f17c0ae0c6bf84c9d9f24b2e3dd8fcd/raw/71cb4490f85efa8615f43f82a6e0f5768e68ee20/quarters-data), it is pretty simple.

I want to draw a line chart with that data. I am finding it difficult to do so with the new version of D3.

I have tried all sorts, but this is what I currently have.

```
var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]);
```

Then later inside the `d3.csv()` call I have

```
x.domain(data, function(d) { return d.date; });
```

That doesn't work, I also tried:

```
var x = d3.scaleOrdinal().range([0, width]);
```

But that too didn't work. I find it easier working with Linear Quantitative scales.

**Update**

Following from Gerardo's correction (good spot by the way), I now get this:

[image: wrong chart]

Comment: Did you have a look at https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245 ?

Comment: Yes I did, but my scales aren't `Time`, hence why I used `scaleOrdinal`

Comment: I know I've called them `Q1 2015` ..etc, but imagine that was `Apples, Oranges` ..etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a scale, the `domain` has to be an array. So, this:

```
x.domain(data, function(d) { return d.date; });
```

Should be:

```
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
```

You can see the difference in these demos. First, your code:

```js
var data = [{date: "Q1 2014", close: 58},
           {date: "Q2 2014", close: 48},
           {date: "Q3 2014", close: 67},
           {date: "Q4 2014", close: 33},
           {date: "Q1 2014", close: 27},
           {date: "Q2 2014", close: 87},
           {date: "Q3 2014", close: 23},
           {date: "Q4 2014", close: 56}];

var scale = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(data, function(d){
  return d.date;
});
                                     
console.log(scale.domain());
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Now, using `map`:

```js
var data = [{date: "Q1 2014", close: 58},
           {date: "Q2 2014", close: 48},
           {date: "Q3 2014", close: 67},
           {date: "Q4 2014", close: 33},
           {date: "Q1 2014", close: 27},
           {date: "Q2 2014", close: 87},
           {date: "Q3 2014", close: 23},
           {date: "Q4 2014", close: 56}];

var scale = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(data.map(function(d){
  return d.date;
}));
                                     
console.log(scale.domain());
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT: Since you are making a line chart, you should use a time scale or another scale, but not an ordinal one. The reason is that an ordinal scale expects the same number of values in the `range` as the number of values in the `domain`. That being said, you can use a [`scalePoint`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scalePoint):

```
var x = d3.scalePoint().range([0, width])
    .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
```

Comment: Very good spot @GerardoFurtado, still looks messed up though, see updated Q.

Comment: [full code here](https://gist.github.com/Ciwan1859/41b81dcdbcca57959fa603c311d4a8a4). Love the explanation with examples, you're ace thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks @GerardoFurtado, that worked. But I'm still not clear on why I can't use `scaleOrdinal`? I thought D3 would be smart enough to say that we have X items in the Domain array, I'm going to split the range distance horizontally and equally, no?

Comment: No, that's not the way an ordinal scale works. Check this fiddle I just made, have a look at the console: https://jsfiddle.net/n2sdgb35/

Comment: ha very surprising to me! thanks again @GerardoFurtado, that behaviour is super weird to me, but I'm sure there's a good reason for it. Much appreciated.